# curious inflection of English words

Tags: wordplay, language, english, connections-puzzle

> The **agent-noun** form of **lingerie** is **frank**.
>
> The **present-participle** form of **military actions** is **lying**.
>
> The **past-tense** form of **sheep** is **permanent**.
>
> The **past-participle** form of **six-pack** is **urn**.

Unfortunately, someone has mix-and-matched these four statements.  Some or all of them should combine a form name, a given form, and a modified form (the three boldfaced components) differently from the way they're combined above.  Can you arrange them back into their proper combinations?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The trick here lies in

> finding synonyms of the bolded words that follow the language pattern provided (but aren't actually related):

The **agent-noun** form of

> **sheep** (*ewes*) is **urn** (*ewer*).
>   -   *Someone who "**ewes**" a lot becomes a great "**ewer**"*.

The **past-tense** form of

> **six-pack** (*abs*) is **lying** (*abed*).
>   -   *He "**abs**" now, but yesterday he "**abed**" even more*.

The **present-participle** form of

> **lingerie** (*undies*) is **permanent** (*undying*).
>   -   *She "**undies**" every day; she really loves "**undying**"*.

The **past-participle** form of

> **military actions** (*ops*) is **frank** (*open*).
>   -   *If one "**ops**" now, it does not necessarily mean that one has "**open**" in the past*.
>  (Like "speaks/spoken".)